# TypeError: __init__() takes at most 3 arguments (8 given)

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing, super, superclass

I'm a new student and have run into an issue that I don't quite understand. I have asked my teacher to explain, but he insists that I seek the advice of others first.

I have reviewed similar issues, but I'm either dense or don't understand how to translate the solutions into my own code.  I would appreciate assistance in solving my problem and learning how to prevent it in the future. The error that I'm receiving reads:

**TypeError: __init__() takes at most 3 arguments (8 given)**

```
class Fighter(ShowBase, object):
    fighterCount = 0
    def __init__(self, modelPath, parentNode, nodeName, posVec, traverser, scaleVec = 1.0):
        super(Fighter, self).__init__(modelPath, parentNode, nodeName, 0, 0, 0, 3.0)
        self.modelNode.setScale(scaleVec)
        self.modelNode.setPos(posVec)

        self.trav = traverser

        self.origin = render.attachNewNode("origin")
        self.origin.setPos(0, 0, 0)
        self.origin.hide()

        self.setKeyBindings()

        self.hud = Hud("./Tools/Hud.x", self.modelNode, "Hud", (0, 10, 0))
```

Comment: Traceback where?

Answer (score 0):

In class `Fighter`, you call `super().__init__` to initialize the instance, which will call base class `ShowBase.__init__`. According to your error message, I guess `ShowBase.__init__` only has three arguments, but you give it eight.